# AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_BLUETOOTH'

Tags: sockets, bluetooth, windows-10, python-3.6

I wanted to use bluetooth in Python to comunicate with my robot, so I looked online for some tutorials. I've found some examples using socket module which I've used before. So I tried to use it, but I'm getting this error `AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_BLUETOOTH'`. I've checked the official python documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html and there it is. I'm using Windows10 and Python3.6.4
complete code:

```
import socket

hostMACAddress = 'adress'
port = 3
backlog = 1
size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.bind((hostMACAddress,port))
s.listen(backlog)
try:
    client, address = s.accept()
    while 1:
        data = client.recv(size)
        if data:
            print(data)
            client.send(data)
except:
    print("Closing socket")
    client.close()
    s.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share you complete code!

Comment: Bluetooth sockets are not available on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I found this old question for a search for this error. This is not a full answer, but it may contain some useful hints.

According to the [BLE Monitor FAQ](https://custom-components.github.io/ble_monitor/faq#i-get-attributeerror-module-socket-has-no-attribute-af_bluetooth-in-home-assistant-after-the-installation-or-python-upgrade) this error occurs when Python has been compiled without Bluetooth support. It may also be as per the comment above that Bluetooth sockets are not available on windows - I don't have any knowledge in this area.

Here's the important text from the link above

**I get AttributeError: module ‘socket’ has no attribute ‘AF_BLUETOOTH’ in Home Assistant after the installation or python upgrade**

> This means that Python is built/installed without support for
> Bluetooth. You will have to rebuild Python 3 with bluetooth.h. When
> using a virtual environment (venv), you can do this with the following
> instructions. Please make a backup first!!!, as you will have to
> delete the venv with Home Assistant and reinstall it in a new venv.
> You might need to modify commands for your own situation and the
> latest python version.

1. Install BT library with

Code below (without this line formatting doesn't work)

```
sudo apt-get install bluetooth libbluetooth-dev
```

2. Rebuild Python:

Code below (without this line formatting doesn't work)

```
cd Python-x.x.x/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Alternative build process. According to text in the Python Makefile "altinstall" deploys python without overwriting older versions.

```
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y build-essential tk-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libreadline6-dev libdb5.3-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libexpat1-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev
sudo make altinstall
```